# How to travel cheaply between Charleroi Airport and Brussels?

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, belgium, brussels, crl

There's a shuttle bus from Charleroi airport to Brussels, but if you book it a couple of days before it costs 15 euros plus 3 euros booking. A train could be a lot cheaper but it's unclear how to get to the train station from the airport.

I have the feeling hitchhiking wouldn't be so hard, but every time I was there it was raining and/or I was already too tired.

What's a good and cheap way to get between Charleroi airport and Brussels?

---

Note: Charleroi airport is not Charleroi.

Comment: Voting to close this one as duplicate of the more recent one. Let's make the linked duplicate the main QA and keep it up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Charleroi Airport website page for "Rail and Bus"](http://www.charleroi-airport.com/en/passengers/acces-and-parking/by-rail-bus/index.html), you'll discover that there's a special shuttle bus between the airport. It's Bus A, and the price is included in the cost of the train ticket if you buy a ticket to/from the airport. It takes about 20 minutes from the airport to the station at Charleroi.

There are special train tickets for travel to/from Charleroi Airport. If you go to the [SNCB website](https://www.belgianrail.be/en/) and search from `CHARLEROI SOUTH AIRPORT` to `ZONE BRUXELLES`, then pick `TICKETS CHARLEROI AIRPORT` from the ticket type dropdown, you'll see the prices. Currently, it's €14,40 one way. You can read more about the combined bus+train tickets for Charleroi [here](https://www.belgianrail.be/en/timetable-and-buy-tickets/Search/secure/~/media/9729EA1FE4334D46BF6F71A24BB9F3C4.ashx). Tickets can be bought online, or at the airport, should be the same price.

Comment: So, the direct bus is €3.60 more expensive for the convenience of not needing to transfer?

Comment: Looks like this Bus A is only going once an hour. The good part is that you can also pay 5 euro separately and then use a Rail Pass, which would mean 7,60 instead of paying 9,40 euro for the ride. So 12,60. But that's not worth the inconvenience of only one bus an hour to me.

Comment: @KasperSouren what do you mean by "you can also pay 5 euro separately"?

Comment: The ticket for bus A only is 5 euro, separate from the train ticket, which you would get if you get a bus+train ticket.

Comment: @KasperSouren Lol, interestingly I'm back. I didn't even realize I posted here before. Anyway, I think this post should be updated, to mention that the 14.40 ticket is indeed a combination of 9.40 for the train and 5 for a day ticket of TEC. But both can become cheaper. **The cheapest would be 9.70 euro** if you pay 7.60 euro for the train by using a railpass and 2.10 euro by buying a single bus ticket instead of a day pass. The last bit might even be cheaper if TEC has a similar system as De Lijn where you can buy 10-drive tickets similar to the railpass but for busses.

Comment: @KasperSouren Also it seems that bus A drive every 30 minutes now.